# Why some windows don't understand the url rest on XAMPP or IIS?

Tags: rest, iis, xampp, slim

Example:

`www.xxx.com.br/user/new/` (It works on some computers).

`www.xxx.com.br/user/index.php/new/` (It works on all computers I tested).

Project Folder:

`user
- index.php`

I using [slim framework](http://www.slimframework.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure URL rewriting is enabled on the server. It's not a client issue, it's a server issue.